# Installing mbstring for PHP 5.3 with a Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker

I have the Dockerfile below for setting up a PHP 5.3 and Apache image which works fine. However, I also want PHP to have the multibyte `mbstring` extensions included, and can't work out what I need to add to this:

```
FROM php:5.3-apache

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys AA8E81B4331F7F50 \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010 \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 9D6D8F6BC857C906

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng-dev

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

I've tried adding `mbstring`, `php-mbstring`, `php5-mbstring`, `php5.3-mbstring`, `php53-php-mbstring` to the `apt-get install` list, but they're never found. What am I missing?

(Yes, I need to use old PHP 5.3 for this.)

Comment: Did you try installing libapache2-mod-php5 beforehand, since it contains mbstring

Comment: When you say "beforehand" do you mean in a particular place? I tried adding it after `libpng-dev` but I get errors when it finds there's a `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.load` file – default action is to keep it – then it says "dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure): EOF on stdin at conffile prompt"

Comment: I would have put it after the apt-get install since if you try to do a normal installation on linux then the order is apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server ... etc

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error. I'm wondering if I should copy what I think is the `php:5.3-apache` Dockerfile, put it in mine instead of importing it, and add something there? https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/0985a4d4ba7d16e273d14ca582562767b823cf08/5.3/Dockerfile

Comment: php*-common? or php*-xml?

Comment: Trying `php53-common` and `php53-xml` I get "Unable to location package..." for both.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *the* answer to my specific question but it's a way round it - instead of using `php:5.3-apache` I found `cespi/php-5.3:apache-latest`, which installs mastering, so now I can just do:

```
FROM cespi/php-5.3:apache-latest

COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```

The image [on DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/cespi/php-5.3/) and [the repo on GitHub](https://github.com/Desarrollo-CeSPI/docker-php-5.3-alpine).